# MySQL multiple Left Join gets wrong output

Tags: mysql

Im a beginner in MySQL. Im trying to query out some data from a voip calling card database for which I needed to join multiple table. It was giving correct output till there was two left join table, but when I added third table then the "total duration" column is giving wrong output.

My First query looked like this and the output was in this screencap [image]

```
select c.login,cname.Name,cname.LastName,DATE_FORMAT(Creation_Date,'%d-%m-%y')as regdate,DATE_FORMAT((Select max(call_start) from calls where calls.id_client = c.id_client),'%d-%m-%y') as lastcall, c.account_state,sum(cdr.duration / 60) as total_duration from clientsshared as c
left join invoiceclients as cname on cname.IdClient = c.id_client
left join calls as cdr on cdr.id_client = c.id_client
where c.id_reseller='10' group by c.id_client order by total_duration desc limit 100
```

The new query is like this which gives wrong output, please check the screencap [image]

```
select c.login,cname.Name,cname.LastName,DATE_FORMAT(Creation_Date,'%m-%d-%y')as regdate, 
(Select max(data) from payments where payments.id_client = c.id_client) as lastpayment,
(Select max(call_start) from calls where calls.id_client = c.id_client) as lastcall, 
c.account_state,sum(cdr.duration / 60) as total_duration from clientsshared as c

left join invoiceclients as cname on cname.IdClient = c.id_client
left join payments as p on p.id_client = c.id_client
left join calls as cdr on cdr.id_client = c.id_client
where c.id_reseller='10' group by c.id_client order by total_duration desc limit 100
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select c.login,cname.Name,cname.LastName,DATE_FORMAT(Creation_Date,'%m-%d-%y')as regdate, 
(Select max(data) from payments where payments.id_client = c.id_client) as lastpayment,
(Select max(call_start) from calls where calls.id_client = c.id_client) as lastcall, 
c.account_state,sum(cdr.duration / 60) as total_duration 

from clientsshared as c

left join invoiceclients as cname on cname.IdClient = c.id_client
left join calls as cdr on cdr.id_client = c.id_client
left join payments as p on p.id_client = cdr.id_client

where c.id_reseller='10' 

group by c.id_client 

order by total_duration desc limit 100
```

Comment: Thanks Melanie, I've tried this but no improvement, can we think of any other way ?

Answer (score 0):

wow, Im not sure how it works but I just removed a `left join` and tried which output the correct value as expected ,

```html
    select c.login,cname.Name,cname.LastName,cname.Creation_Date as regdate, 
 (Select max(data) from payments where payments.id_client = c.id_client) as lastpayment,
 (Select max(call_start) from calls where calls.id_client = c.id_client) as lastcall, 
 c.account_state,sum(cdr.duration / 60) as total_duration 

 from clientsshared as c

 left join invoiceclients as cname on cname.IdClient = c.id_client
 left join calls as cdr on cdr.id_client = c.id_client

 where c.id_reseller='10' 

 group by c.id_client 

 order by total_duration desc
```

Answer (score 0):

When you join tables it creates a multiple of the number of rows

For example if there is 2 calls on average in the calls table for each client then you get 2x the number of client rows, then if there are 3 payments on average per client that is 3x(2x) the number of clients. This multiplier effect can lead to errors when doing aggregates. To avoid this issue it can be necessary to group BEFORE you join as a subquery.

Please try this:

```
SELECT c.LOGIN
 ,cname.NAME
 ,cname.LastName
 ,DATE_FORMAT(Creation_Date, '%d-%m-%y') AS regdate
 ,p.lastpayment
 ,DATE_FORMAT(max(cdr.call_start), '%d-%m-%y') AS lastcall
 ,c.account_state
 ,sum(cdr.duration / 60) AS total_duration
FROM clientsshared AS c
LEFT JOIN invoiceclients AS cname ON cname.IdClient = c.id_client
LEFT JOIN calls AS cdr ON cdr.id_client = c.id_client
LEFT JOIN (
 SELECT id_client
  ,max(data) AS lastpayment
 FROM payments
 GROUP BY id_client
 ) p ON p.id_client = c.id_client
WHERE c.id_reseller = '10'
GROUP BY c.id_client
ORDER BY total_duration DESC limit 100
```

Please also note that you have joined the calls table, so there should be no need to do this "correlated subquery"

```
 ,DATE_FORMAT((
   SELECT max(call_start)
   FROM calls
   WHERE calls.id_client = c.id_client
   ), '%d-%m-%y') AS lastcall
```

instead all you should need is:

```
 ,DATE_FORMAT(max(cdr.call_start), '%d-%m-%y') AS lastcall
```